# sveltekit component doesn't inherit parent styling when using ssr

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

#### Context:

Starting with a barebones project, I have the default main page `routes/+page.svelte` and my component under `lib/Component.svelte`.

The structure looks like this:

```
├── src
    ├── lib
    │   └── Component.svelte
    └── routes
        └── +page.svelte
```

`Component.svelte`:

The component is just a simple `div` with a `slot`, and the `div` has some properties set, to make it flex and give it colour.

```html
<div id="line">
    <slot></slot>
</div>

<style>
    #line {
        display: flex;
        gap: 16px;
    }
</style>
```

`+page.svelte`:

I import the `Component`, and display it inside of a `p` that has a `font-size` and `font-weight` set.

```html
<script>
    import Component from "$lib/Component.svelte";
</script>

<p id="para">
    <Component>
        <p>some text...</p>
        <p>some text...</p>
    </Component>
</p>

<style>
    #para {
        font-size: 36px;
        font-weight: 500;
    }
</style>
```

#### Problem:

What ends up happening is when the page first loads, the ssr page is displayed first, but you'll notice the component is rendered outside of the parent `p` (id=para) in the DOM. Then it'll add it inside the `p`, and inherit the font size and weight.
This creates a visual flash of the static content that doesn't have the correct properties.

Upon examining the static build folder vs the live site (with `npm run dev`), you can see how the component is rendered outside of the parent it's supposed to be in.

[image: screenshot]

[image: video]

#### Some additional info:

- I'm using the static adapter, with `export const prerender = true` set in `routes/+layout.js`
- My `svelte.config.js` is setup to use the static adapter

The obvious workaround is to apply to parent styles directly to the component, but unfortunately my use case has varying styles (of the parent) that I cannot apply directly to the component.

###### Am I missing something very fundamental/obvious that I am not currently doing?

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would suspect that this happens because this is invalid HTML.

You are not allowed to add block content to a paragraph, i.e. a `<div>` or other `<p>` cannot be within a `<p>` which might cause the parser to close the current (outer) paragraph.

Paragraphs are supposed to contain primarily text, their content model is [phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_categories#phrasing_content).

Comment: Right, didn't occur to me that it was because of the `p`! Switching the parent to a `div` fixed this. Thank you!